# Calculating (A - B(D^-1)B^T )^-1 with CUDA

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication, equation, matrix-inverse, symmetric

What might be the most efficient way of calculating the following expression using **CUDA C** ?

**(A - B(D^-1)B^T )^-1**

where **D** is a very large symmetric matrix and **A** is a small symmetric matrix, which makes **B** and **B^T** medium sized rectangular non-symmetric matrices. Of course (^-1) and (^T) are the inverse and transpose operations, respectively.

Comment: That's an expression, not an equation...

Comment: Matrix inversion could be performed by [CULA Matrix Inversion](http://www.culatools.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=141) or [MAGMA Matrix Inversion](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=571) routines. For matrix multiplications, including transpositions, you could use `cuBLAS` routines. This would be the easiest way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Oli you are right, I corrected.

Comment: @Jack thanks for the inversion routines. I do have a specific [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292258/packed-symmetric-matrix-matrix-multiplication-with-cuda) for the multiplication. Could you help me with that ?

Comment: I'm not aware of that possibility. Perhaps, packed storage could be difficult to be efficiently implemented on GPUs and I do not think there is much demand for that in the community.

Comment: All of those operations are available in [ArrayFire](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire), including matrix multiplication, inversion, transpose, solving linear systems, element-wise operations, etc, all without writing any low-level kernels, which we work on at AccelerEyes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are available to "low" level programming, then matrix inversion could be performed by [CULA](http://www.culatools.com/) or [MAGMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) libraries.

CULA Dense contains single (real or complex) precision of System Solve, Linear Least Squares Solve, and Constrained Linear Least Squares Solve. CULA Sparse is a collection of iterative solvers for sparse matrices. Magma contains `dgetrf` and `dgetri` to calculate inverses of square double precision matrices.

For matrix multiplications, including transpositions, you could use `cuBLAS` routines.

If you prefer "higher" level programming, then [ArrayFire](http://www.accelereyes.com/products/arrayfire) enables you to perform matrix multiplications, inversions, transposes, solution of linear systems, and elementwise operations with a more naturale mathematical syntax. Also, Matlab has a [GPU Computing Support for NVIDIA CUDA-Enabled GPUs](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html).

Comment: Its seems that only CULA and MAGMA are free. For the symmetric matrix inversion I need to use `ZPOTRF` and `ZPOTRI` functions sequentially, which are all avaliable in MAGMA but not in CULA. However, I could not install MAGMA, since it does not have a detailed readme file and I have very limited experience about installing libraries. So, any help with that is appreciated.

Comment: Please, note that the basic functions of ArrayFire are free, see [ArrayFire Licensing](http://www.accelereyes.com/products/arrayfire_licensing). Perhaps you will find there matrix multiplication and transpose, but not matrix inversion. If you have issues in installing MAGMA, could you refer to their [forum](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/)? As an alternative, you could use [Matlab's GPU computation functionalities](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gpu.html) (I will add this to my answer), if you happen to have access to a licensed product.

Comment: Thanks, I must to use C/C++ and Visual Studio. I also need double complex precision but most free libraries do not support this. In this case only MAGMA fits to me, but even in their forum I couldn't find a clear response to how to install MAGMA and use it with Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other library fulfilling your requirements.